# how to extract a quote from a quote generator in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

im trying to extract a quote from this quote gen URL 'http://www.quotedb.com/quote/quote.php?action=random_quote'. i need it to extract JUST the quote and optionally the person who made the quote. this is an example reply from the generator.

document.write('When nothing seems to help, I go and look at a stonecutter hammering away at his rock perhaps a hundred times without as much as a crack showing in it. Yet at the hundred and first blow it will split in two, and I know it was not that blow that did it, but all that had gone before.
');
document.write('*More quotes from [Jacob August Riis](http://www.quotedb.com/authors/jacob-august-riis)*');

I know i need to parse it to extract the quote itself but im not to sure how to so this.
I know how to download the string of the quote but not how to extract it. So this is all i have currently:

```
        Dim Cient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim grab = Cient.DownloadString("http://www.quotedb.com/quote/quote.php?action=random_quote")
```

any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else could probably come up with more elegant regular expressions, but this should work.  Just a couple of regular expressions to extract the parts of the returned data that you are interested in.

```
Dim quote = RegEx.Matches(grab, "document\.write\('(.*?)<br>'\);")(0).Groups(1).Value
Dim author = RegEx.Matches(grab, "document\.write\('<i>.*?>(.*?)</a></i>'\);")(0).Groups(1).Value
```

Comment: Worked perfect! also very clean and just a single line! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of parsing HTML with Regex, but since all of these come back with the same grammar so to speak, we can consider it regular for this case.

```
Dim pattern As String = <![CDATA[document\.write\('(?<quote>.*)<br\>'\);\ndocument\.write\('.*href=\"(?<url>[^\"]*)\">(?<author>[^<]*)</a>.*'\).*]]>.Value

Dim quoteRegex As New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline)

Dim Cient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim grab = Cient.DownloadString("http://www.quotedb.com/quote/quote.php?action=random_quote")

Dim matches As MatchCollection = quoteRegex.Matches(grab)
For Each m As Match In matches
    Console.WriteLine("Quote: {0}", m.Groups("quote"))
    Console.WriteLine("Author: {0}", m.Groups("author"))
    Console.WriteLine("URL: {0}", m.Groups("url"))
Next
```

This finds the quote (text within the first `document.write()` ignoring the quotes and the `<br>` tag), the Author of the quote (the Textual display of the `anchor` tag) and then the URL for more quotes (the `href` attribute of the anchor)

I declared the pattern by using XML literals so that I didn't have to escape out all the quote characters.

Requires `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Comment: Your code didn't seem to work, not to sure why. i tried Mark's code and it worked. thanks for your effort anyways!

Comment: I ran it in a loop for over three hours yesterday watching it print out everything. What didn't work about it? May be that you need to add `.Value` after the `Group("groupname")` when assigning to string